# Написание модульного теста соединения с базой данных jest

Tags: node.js, юнит-тесты, jest

Пытаюсь разобраться в модульном тестировании и написать тесты к проекту. Почитал документацию и застрял, так как там описаны тесты ситуаций до которых я еще не дошел. А у меня следующее:

Например есть тест проверяющий корректность работы соединения с базой данных.

```
require('iconv-lite').encodingExists('foo')
const pool = require('../database/pool')

describe('Работа с базой', () => {
    test('Подключение к базе данных', ()=>{
        pool.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users', (err, results)=>{
            expect(results.status_code).toBe(200)
        })
    })
})
```

Тест конечно очень глупый, но пока лучше не придумал. Тестирование он проходит, но в консоле падает ошибка:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status_code' of undefined
```

Я посмотрел в объект `results`, у него нет такого свойства и ничего похожего тоже нет. Как мне тогда переделать тест, чтобы он работал без ошибок? Или мне вообще стоит его полностью изменить? Любая помощь принимается.

Внес небольшие изменения:

```
test('Подключение к базе данных', async ()=>{
    await pool.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users', (err, results)=>{
        if (err) { throw err; }
        else{
        expect(results.status_code).toBe(200)}
    })
})
```

Тогда тест также проходит, но ошибка всё-равно падает: `TypeError: authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function`.

Comment: 1) поставь `if (err) { throw err; }` 2) ну проверь что-то в results: "results является массивом", "results не пуст", "первый элемент массива results является объектом, содержит ключ count и значение count является цифрой и значение count больше равно 0"

Comment: Это не совсем, то что я пытаюсь сделать. Я пытаюсь проверить что соединение существует вообще. Поскольку ничего лучше не придумал, то хочу просто сделать запрос к базе. Соответственно если есть доступ и таблица, то с соединение работает. А вот про количество записей ничего не знаю, т.е. пока что их 0, а потом может измениться, а тест должен работать

Comment: Все дело в том, что в доке по Jest указано как проверять 2+2, а вот чуть более сложные вещи отсутствуют. Вообще нигде в интернете ничего более менее подходящего.

Comment: чтобы проверить наличие коннекта достаточно `select 1` или `select now()`

Comment: Модульный тест должен проверять правильность работы какого-то модуля. Проверка соединения не входит в обязанности юнит-тестов.

Comment: Хорошо, возможно мой тест не имеет смысла. Я пытаюсь понять как по аналогии написать вообще такие тесты. Например, у меня файл в котором происходит формирование путей, обработка различных переменных с присвоением значений и далее вызов следующего обработчика. Такой файл будет являться модулем?

Comment: А если вернуться к работе с базой, то у меня будет обработчик `insert` его я должен тестить? И как правильно это сделать? Или это лучше в отдельный вопрос вынести?